# How does the gun get back?

Tags: plot-explanation, magnolia

In the movie Magnolia, the cop's gun is stolen (I think by that kid who raps). After the rain of frogs, the gun falls to the ground too. Where does the gun come from?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The gun is picked up by Dixon, and later thrown off a moving car. If the car was going over a bridge, it'd certainly explain how it landed there. This later scene is only in the script, not in the movie.

> Worm's car drives down the street. LONG LENS.  ANGLE, at the car, 
>        Dixon leans up and out the window a bit....he's got the gun wrapped
>        in newspaper, taking the fingerprints from the gun....he throws
>        the POLICE ISSUED WEAPON from the speeding car...

http://www.dailyscript.com/scripts/magnolia.html

Comment: awesome answer! Looks like an entire character - "Worm" was removed from the film (Dixon's dad). Thanks @cyberclaw!

Answer (score 0):

Some would argue it is providence, given the frogs, but ultimately an explanation is never provided.

[image: Stanley Spector (Jeremy Blackman)]

According to Stanley Spector (Jeremy Blackman), the browbeaten child prodigy unhappily competing as a *What Do Kids Know?* contestant, it's just *something that happens*:

> The film has an underlying theme of unexplained events, taken from the
>   1920s and 1930s works of Charles Fort, an American writer and
>   researcher who specialized in anomalous phenomena. One of Fort's books
>   is visible [in the film] ... and the movie's end credits thank Charles
>   Fort.

***[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnolia_(film))***